# 'Expected an indented block' Error

Tags: python, function, block

```
#define welcome as the main menu page for editing editing details.
def welcome():
    print ('Welcome to SUNI-DAYS VILLA \n \nPlease choose to edit from the following:\n\n1-Personal Details\n2-Holiday Option\n3-Villa Options\n4-Additional Options\n\n0-Exit')
    ('\n')
    main_option = input ('Option:')
#After choosing option, run their choice 
    if main_option ==('1'):
        cust_opt()
    if main_option ==('2'):
        holiday_opt()
    if main_option ==('3'):
        villa_opt()
    if main_option ==('4'):
        add_opt()
    if main_option ==('0'):
        quit()
    elif print ('Please choose a valid option:'):

welcome()

    #Option 1- from welcome()
    def cust_opt():

    print ('Please answer ALL of the questions')
    cust_title = input ('Choose an option:\n1-Mr\n2-Mrs\n3-Miss\n4-Ms\nTitle:')
    if cust_title ==('1'):
        cust_title1 ==('Mr')
    if cust_title ==('2'):
        cust_title1 ==('Mrs')
    if cust_title ==('3'):
        cust_title1 ==('Miss')
    if cust_title ==('4'):
        cust_title1 ==('Ms')
    elif print ('Please choose your title')
    cust_name = input ('Full Name:')
    cust_age = input ('Age:')
    cust_dono = input ('Door/Flat number:')
    cust_str = input ('Street Name:')
    cust_city = input ('City:')
    cust_post = input ('Postcode:')

    print(cus_title1 , cust_name, \ncust_age 'years old.',\n'Address:' ,       cust_dono, cust_str, \ncust_city, \ncust_post)
```

'Expected an indented block' Error is given after 'welcome()' 
kinda sucks since i just started learning it and im going mental already.
so i used def to write bunch of function and then to run it I did 'welcome()' 
.. isnt that what i was suppose to do

Comment: You are missing a line after `elif print("Please choose a valid option:"):`

Comment: `def cust_opt():` should not be indented.

Comment: What do you expect this line to do? `elif print ('Please choose a valid option:'):` Maybe you mean `else: print('Please choose a valid option:')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error says - your indentation is off. [Indentation is very important in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-does-python-use-indentation-for-grouping-of-statements).

You may also want to [use a `while` loop for validating input](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23294659/5903421).

```
def welcome():
    # ...
    else:
        print ('Please choose a valid option:')
    return

welcome()

def cust_opt():
    # ...
    else:
        print ('Please choose your title')
    # ...
    return
```